# How to send Messages From Struts Action class to jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Hey i am new to struts2 or even to Struts so, i was looking the ways by which we can pass messages from action class to jsp page

- i.e I have a login page and if login fails then i want to send error message to jsp page for what reasons the login was failed or even if login was successful then i want to show a login successful popup to the user

Thanks

Comment: You will have to use ajax for this.

Comment: depends on how the login form is submitted. It is normal form submission or an ajax submission ?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi Ajax login is slightly different then normal form login.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can pass messages to jsp in struts2.You can use a code like this `addActionMessage("You are valid user!");`   in the action class.
I think you need to extend ActionSupport for this.
http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-actionerror-actionmessage-example/

Answer (score 1):

In your action

```
addActionMessage("Welcome")
addErrorMessage("Not Logged in")
```

in your jsp:

```
 <s:actionmessage/>
 <s:actionerror/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your action class, you will be calling `addActionMessage()` for success message and `addActionError()` for the failure message.

To display the error on the JSPs you will use `<s:actionmessage />` and `<s:actionerror />`.